# Sort facet by groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(c(1,5,2,6,4,3), each=5),
                 group=rep(c(1,2,2,2,1,1), each=5),
                 var1=runif(30))
```

I now want to plot `var1` using `ggplot` and facet the plot by `id`, but sort the facets by `group` (and by `id` within `group`). I gather that I have to make `id` a factor with levels that sort neatly by `group` but I cannot figure out how to accomplish this elegantly.

Comment: Search for something along the lines of "sorting factor levels". This question has been addressed before.

Comment: See [this](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/) and [this](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot-revisited/?relatedposts_exclude=527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# sort by group and id
df_sorted <- df[with(df, order(group, id)), ]
# reorder factor levels
df_sorted$id <- factor(df_sorted$id, levels=unique(df_sorted$id))
# plot something
ggplot(df_sorted, aes(var1)) + facet_wrap(~id) + geom_density()
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't need to be an ordered factor, just a factor in the right order.

Comment: It is not: I did not specify `order=TRUE`, did I? I reordered factor levels, but the factor did not become ordered.

Comment: The comment is for the benefit of onlookers. Not for your code.

Comment: Ah, all right then, my bad. Reordering factor levels without making an ordered factor may indeed be confusing.